# How can I access an external table in a MySQL database?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, importing-exporting, database

I have a database (MySQL) with information about food.

It has several columns, for example:

```
-----------------------------------------
| product name | calories | fat | unit  |
-----------------------------------------
| bread        | 100      | 10  | grams |
| potatoes     |  50      | 20  | grams |
-----------------------------------------
```

Is there anyway way to import this dataset into Drupal and work with it in a field type, perhaps with taxonomy? Or should I program my own module?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a module that will help you: http://drupal.org/project/data

[ edit re MPD suggestion below ...]

This module will help by providing an automatic Views integration for your data, meaning that you can show the data via Views.

It also includes an API which simplifies custom programming to get access to your data (perhaps for use in preprocess functions, which would permit the data to be themed on a node page, etc.)

Regarding your desire to include taxonomy, one way to do that would be to fold the data onto a node and then attach taxonomy to that node, however, that might depend on how you're mapping your data onto individual nodes.

Comment: Can you describe Ho this will help?

Comment: I checked that module, and it seems very promising it is also causing a lot of errors. If anyone has an alternative suggestions I am all open for it :)

Comment: Data would provide you CRUD of your table. Forena is just reporting.

Comment: I just tried out Data on Simplytest.me with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Module [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) can be used to query (not update) any MySQL database table.

For more details about Forena, 2 types of documentation are available:

- [Community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2041363).
- Documentation that comes with Forena, which you can access right after install and enable of the module. Checkout the [demo site](http://www.forenasolutions.org) for an online example of the current:

  - **Forena documentation** - use the link 'Reporting documentation' or visit relative link /reports/help.
  - **Forena samples** - use the link 'Reporting samples' or visit relative link /reports/samples (these samples are fully functional, so make sure to experiment a bit with it, such as the drill downs available on the SVG Graph sample).

Disclosure: I'm a **co**-maintainer of this module,
I hope this does not violate the site's [policy on self-promotion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion).